# Flutter SSL Cause Response is poor and CachedNetworkImage does not display images with url that has https while i can see it in browser

Tags: wordpress, flutter, ssl

Every thing works fine [ i mean send request and response time and access image by CachedNetworkImage ] until start using SSL change that is [

```
 Future<void> WooSSLLoader() async {
 final certificateAsset = await rootBundle.load('assets/WooCertificate.pem');
 final certificateBytes = certificateAsset.buffer.asUint8List();

 SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
 securityContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(certificateBytes);
 securityContext.useCertificateChainBytes(certificateBytes);


 List<String> alpnProtocols = ['h2', 'http/1.1'];
 securityContext.setAlpnProtocols(alpnProtocols, true);
 }
 Future<products> getProductByCategory(String catId) async {
 late products product_List;
 // TODO: implement getProductByCategory
 int maxRetries = 20;
 int currentRetry = 0;

 while (currentRetry < maxRetries) {
 try {
   var response = await http.get(
       Uri.parse(getOAuthURL(
           "GET",
           'https://engy.jerma.net/wp-json/wc/v3/products?category=' +
               catId +
               "&status=publish")),
       headers: {"Content-Type": "Application/json"}).timeout(
       Duration(seconds: 12));

   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     product_List = products.fromJson(response.body);
   break;
   }
   } catch (error) {
   // Handle error
   currentRetry++;
   }
   }

   return product_List;
   }
```

]
as you can see i forced to use while loop and time out to get response
from WooCommerce API that mean what Flutter code need configuration other
that we have to be able to call API and get response faster and Access Images ,
as you can see i need 20 request to get success response, Can Any Body give Hand